# Find every possibility to insert random number into a string? (python)

Tags: python, string, list, insert, numbers

I'm new to programming and for an exercise I need to create a list of every possibility to insert a random number (from 0 to 9) in to a string. The number can be inserted et every position in this string.

For example I have the string "Aht50rj2" and I need to find every possibility to insert one number at any position in this string (including the beginning and the end).

So far I wasn't able to find a way to solve this. What is the best way to do this?

Edit:
The Input is a String (like for example "Aht50rj2")
And the expected output is a list with all possible ways.
For example ["0Aht50rj2", "Ah1t50rj2", "Aht50rj29", "Aht501rj2", etc.]

Comment: Can you please provide a input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def possibility(word):
    possibilities = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        for j in range(len(word)+1):
            H  = [k for k in word]
            H.insert(j,str(i))
            possibilities.append(''.join(H))
    return possibilities
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but try my code and see if it worked:

```
import random   # import module "random"

example_string = input('Input a string: ') # Asks user to input a string

length_of_string= len(example_string)  # Counts how many characters there are in the string, it'll make sense trust me

example_list=[]  # Create a temporary list
example_list[:0]=example_string  # Get string, turns it into list

example_list.insert(random.randrange(0, length_of_string), str(random.randrange(0, 9)))  # Insert a random number into a random position of the list

list_into_string= ''.join(example_list)  # Get string, turns it into string
print(list_into_string)  # Print result
```

Result number 1:

```
Input a string: stackoverflow
sta1ckoverflow
```

Result number 2:

```
Input a string: stackoverflow
stacko8verflow
```

Result number 3:

```
Input a string: stackoverflow
stackoverfl5ow
```